# Shut-off specific javascript for 5 second after its own activation / preventing sound mixing

Tags: javascript, html

I have large off-line quiz show in HTML, and it basically revealing questions on the board (like Jeopardy). Everything is working perfectly, but I need a last function, which is "buzzer".

With stackoverflow help, I simply constructed it with this javascript:

```
var sounds = {
16 : 'Player1', // key 'Shift'
32 : 'Player2', // key 'Spacebar'
17 : 'Player3', // key 'Ctrl' 
};
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var soundId = sounds[e.keyCode];
if (soundId) document.getElementById(soundId).play();
else console.log("key not mapped : code is", e.keyCode);
}
```

Which is activated inside HTML document body with tags:

```
<audio id=Player1 src=zvuky/Prihlasenie1.mp3>
<audio id=Player2 src=zvuky/Prihlasenie2.mp3>
<audio id=Player3 src=zvuky/Prihlasenie3.mp3>
```

Two or three players sits behind one keyboard and when they knows the answer, they press SHIFT, CTRL or SPACEBAR.

It works fine when they pressing keys alone, or with delay. Problem is, they may press their keys in same time, and then two or three sounds are mixed together (and it impossible to tell who was first).

Maybe there is a complicated way to check, who was first and show it, but I don't think I need it. Every sound is different. It start with different buzzing (1 sec) and after that, there is a human voice (cca 3 seconds) who says "player 1" for example. So when sounds don't mix, everyone knows who pressed the key.

Is there a simple way to adjust this script, so after activation (any of that three sound starts play), it shut it self off for five second (so no keys activating their sounds), and then it start working again?

I can't reload page after every question (quiz is loaded), so it can't be "one-activation-only" script.

Comment: It's a good idea to enclose HTML attribute values in quotes, especially where punctuation or non–alphabetic characters are included. Yes, it's possible to do what you ask. What have you tried? Maybe set a timestamp when a button is pressed. If another is pressed within say 5 seconds, don't play the sound.

Comment: Use 3 boolean flags one for each sound before playing any sound just check if all 3 are false then make the current flag true then proceed after sound finishes make this flag false again

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout`

```
var sounds = {
16 : 'Player1', // key 'Shift'
32 : 'Player2', // key 'Spacebar'
17 : 'Player3', // key 'Ctrl' 
};
var ableToPlaySound = true
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var soundId = sounds[e.keyCode];
if (soundId){
  if(ableToPlaySound){
    ableToPlaySound = false
    console.log(soundId + ' playing')
    setTimeout(function(){ableToPlaySound=true}, 5000)
  } else {
    console.log('sorry, ' + soundId + ', someone is already playing')
  }
}

else console.log("key not mapped : code is", e.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much @Isaac. It didn't work in this exact state, but I was able spot the problem. If I delete row with console.log(soundId + ' playing') and change it to document.getElementById(soundId).play(); from previous code, it start working, and it works exactly as expected. I'm not a programmer, so when I need something like this, I simply googling a code from someone else, try to understand it and then do a simple adjustment according to my needs. I tried it for hours, but I was not able do it from scratch like this. You quickly solve it. Thank you and have good day.